# google pagespeed insights - Scanning Issue

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to test a website https://www.hts.com/ using google pagespeed insights and getting backend error.

[image]

Please let me know if you can help us here to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading the site with Developer Tools open.

Someone has left a `debugger;` statement at line 113 of alian_custom.js, and line 21 of the page within an inline JavaScript block.

This will then mean that the Lighthouse engine hangs (as it doesn't know how to unpause the debugger it seems) and you get a backend error due to a timeout.

Remove these 2 lines and try again, I would think it will work.